# Issue implementing STHorizontalPicker in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I am trying to implement STHorizontalPicker open source code in Table Views.I am using XCode 4.6.2. I have imported Quartz core framework and have implemented this code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    STHorizontalPicker *horizontalPickerView = [[STHorizontalPicker alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    horizontalPickerView.name = @"myPicker";
    [horizontalPickerView setMinimumValue:0.0];
    [horizontalPickerView setMaximumValue:100.0];
    [horizontalPickerView setSteps:100];
    [horizontalPickerView setDelegate:self];
    [horizontalPickerView setValue:50.0];

    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question ?

Comment: I am unable to display the horizontal picker view. I think I need to display the picker view by adding the subview but I dont know how to do that...

Comment: Did you try `[cell.contentView addSubview:horizontalPickerView]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the error you are getting, but this is what I encountered when I just imported this into one of my own projects.

The current version of STHorizontalPicker on GitHub uses manual retain/release. This is incompatible with automatic reference counting (ARC), which is the current preferred method of memory management.

Thankfully, there is an easy way to convert old code to use ARC in Xcode.

After importing the files into Xcode, select Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC. A wizard will appear and in the first step, select STHorizontalPicker.m then you go through the wizard with the default settings.

Comment: I am just unable to display the horizontal picker. I fixed those errors but removing the release/dealloc methods.